# Printing " (double quote) in GoLang

Tags: string, go, quote

I am writing a Go code which reads from a file. To do so I use `fmt.Println()` to print into that intermediate file.

How can I print `"`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is very easy, Just like C.

```
fmt.Println("\"")
```

Comment: More easily even `fmt.Println(\`"\`)`

Answer (score 40):

Old style string literals and their escapes can often be avoided. The typical Go solution is to use a [raw string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) here:

```
 fmt.Println(`"`)
```

Answer (score 22):

Don't say Go doesn't leave you options. The following all print a quotation mark `"`:

```
fmt.Println("\"")
fmt.Println("\x22")
fmt.Println("\u0022")
fmt.Println("\042")
fmt.Println(`"`)
fmt.Println(string('"'))
fmt.Println(string([]byte{'"'}))
fmt.Printf("%c\n", '"')
fmt.Printf("%s\n", []byte{'"'})

// Seriously, this one is just for demonstration not production :)
fmt.Println(xml.Header[14:15])
fmt.Println(strconv.Quote("")[:1])
```

Try them on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-ywYwcBHkH).

Answer (score 10):

- fmt.Printf("test: %q", "bla")
- output: test: "bla"
- [play ground here](https://play.golang.org/p/eO6HghCPZW2)
- [docs here](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)